# Multi-signature contract with offline signing

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation, signature, multisignature

Is it possible to create a multi-signature contract that would not require a transaction for every signature (since this is quite expensive for a higher number of transactions)?

Is it possible to collect signatures offline and broadcast all of them in one on-chain transaction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can achieve this by using signatures of the member keys instead of transactions.

To achieve this, each members of the multisig can sign a message attesting that they approve of the transaction. They can then give their signatures to a single entity who broadcasts the transaction that includes all the signatures as data. On-chain, the smart contract will take each signature and recover each of the signers original addresses and compare that to a mapping of addresses stored in a mapping.

Gnosis Safe does it [here](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/development/contracts/GnosisSafe.sol#L193).

Answer (score 1):

There's [Simple Multisig](https://github.com/christianlundkvist/simple-multisig), by Christian Lundkvist, that requires sending all signatures in a single transaction.

It has a [execute function](https://github.com/christianlundkvist/simple-multisig/blob/master/contracts/SimpleMultiSig.sol#L49-L72) that validates the signatures and executes the operation requested:

```
function execute(
    uint8[] sigV, 
    bytes32[] sigR, 
    bytes32[] sigS, 
    address destination, 
    uint value, 
    bytes data, 
    address executor, 
    uint gasLimit) public
```

There's an article by the author for the previous version: [Exploring Simpler Ethereum Multisig Contracts](https://medium.com/@ChrisLundkvist/exploring-simpler-ethereum-multisig-contracts-b71020c19037).